# Why is ~/.local/share a two-level directory?

Tags: linux, unix, standards, xdg

I've never seen anything under `~/.local` other than `share`, and the [XDG Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) doesn't mention any other directories under `.local`. What is the motivation for having two levels of directories here as opposed to just one (like `~/.config`)?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in line with [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)'s `/usr` and `/usr/local` directories. As the link says, `/share` is a subdirectory for architecture-independent data.

In fact, [there are ongoing efforts to move the full user-specific tertiary hierarchy into `$HOME/.local` from `$HOME`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path). The apparent benefit is they won't clutter the view of your home folder (which is supposed to contain your work files, after all) because names starting with dot aren't shown by default.